# Stop beanreader parser from un-escaping &lt

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, betwixt

Ok, I have edited this question because I have gained a better understanding of betwixt reader and betwixt writer, however I am trying to stop betwixt reader to stop unescaping the `&lt;` within text nodes of each element, at the minute it is doing so and converting it backt to the < angle bracket. How can I prevent this.

Comment: when you show us the relevant codeparts, your expected output and the actual output we'd probably understand your problem better and might be able to help you solve it. Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: problem updated - hope it explains the problem better.